# Error Regarding undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass. Podfile issue Macbook m1 React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, google-maps, cocoapods

I am getting the mentioned error when implementing the react-native map in my project. Specifically, following the react-native map documentation followin code must be implemented in podfile:

```
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
```

However, these lines of code are crushing the app with the described error. How to implement ios map?

Error:"Error output from CocoaPods: Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass"